# How to set TEXT height for input tag?

Tags: html, css

I need the text to be entered to the full width and then transferred to a new line. The number of lines is not limited. And so that the text starts from the beginning of the input tag and not in the middle.

I tried to set the height but only the height of the input changes (Not the height of the text field).

---

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" placeholder="Message*" class="in__message">
```

---

**CSS**

```
input{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(194, 191, 203, 0.7);
    background: rgba(0, 0,0, 0);
    color: rgba(194, 191, 203, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 205px;
}
```

---

In general, you need to place the text on top and make an infinite height and transfer to another line as the width of the block is filled.

Comment: I think you want `<textarea>`, not `<input>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>` element:

```css
textarea{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(194, 191, 203, 0.7);
    background: rgba(0, 0,0, 0);
    color: rgba(194, 191, 203, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 205px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" name="text" placeholder="Message*" class="in__message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text">
```

is always a single line. Try this instead:

```
<input type="textarea">
```